# Has anyone seen a programming puzzle similar to this?

Tags: language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

"Suppose you want to build a solid panel out of rows of 4×1 and 6×1 Lego blocks. For structural strength, the spaces between the blocks must never line up in adjacent rows. As an example, the 18×3 panel shown below is not acceptable, because the spaces between the blocks in the top two rows line up.

There are 2 ways to build a 10×1 panel, 2 ways to build a 10×2 panel, 8 ways to build an 18×3 panel, and 7958 ways to build a 36×5 panel.

How many different ways are there to build a 64×10 panel? The answer will fit in a 64-bit signed integer. Write a program to calculate the answer. Your program should run very quickly – certainly, it should not take longer than one minute, even on an older machine. Let us know the value your program computes, how long it took your program to calculate that value, and on what kind of machine you ran it. Include the program’s source code as an attachment.
"

I was recently given a programming puzzle and have been racking my brains trying to solve it.  I wrote some code using c++ and I know the number is huge...my program ran for a few hours before I decided just to stop it because the requirement was 1 minute of run time even on a slow computer.  Has anyone seen a puzzle similar to this?  It has been a few weeks and I can't hand this in anymore, but this has really been bugging me that I couldn't solve it correctly.  Any suggestions on algorithms to use? Or maybe possible ways to solve it that are "outside the box".  What i resorted to was making a program that built each possible "layer" of 4x1 and 6x1 blocks to make a 64x1 layer.  That turned out to be about 3300 different layers.  Then I had my program run through and stack them into all possible 10 layer high walls that have no cracks that line up...as you can see this solution would take a long, long, long time. So obviously brute force does not seem to be effective in solving this within the time constraint.  Any suggestions/insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there supposed to be images here? I don't see any. I'm guessing it's because you aren't allowed to post images unless you have more than 15 Rep.

Comment: Integer partitioning might be part of the solution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_partition

Comment: I think your 3,300 figure is wrong, it's closer to 47,000 based on a program I whipped up. Perhaps you didn't take order into account.

Comment: @Pax: No, he's right.  3328 ways.  (Based not on a program, but simple combinatorics)  There are 10 ways to have 1 four-board and 10 six-boards.  There are 495 ways to have 4 four-boards and 8 six-boards (495 == 12 choose 4).  There are 1716 ways to have 7 four-boards and 6 six-boards (1716 == 13 choose 7).  Etc.  Keep increasing the number of four-boards by 3, and decreasing the six-boards by 2.  Then sum all the possibilities: 10 + 495 + 1716 + 1001 + 105 + 1 = 3228. (for what I mean by "choose", see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

Comment: @Daniel, I found the problem with my code (PEBCAK). One minor change, there are 11 ways to arrange 1x4+10x6. Other than that, your figures are correct.

Comment: On the plus side, I got a solution I feel good about.  On the minus side, I lost a night of sleep on this one.  Thanks.

Comment: Yea I lost many nights of sleep to this one. I kept trying to find a way to figure it out with a math formula instead of using brute force. A lot of the answers that people have given are very helpful. I am most interested in seeing if someone can come up with a reasonable solution using c++. Thanks so much everyone!

Comment: @T.Flynn6 Did you implement the solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

The main insight is this: when determining what's in row 3, you don't care about what's in row 1, just what's in row 2.

So let's call how to build a 64x1 layer a "row scenario".  You say that there are about 3300 row scenarios.  That's not so bad.

Let's compute a function:

f(s, r) = the number of ways to put row scenario number "s" into row "r", and legally fill all the rows above "r".

(I'm counting with row "1" at the top, and row "10" at the bottom)

STOP READING NOW IF YOU WANT TO AVOID SPOILERS.

Now clearly (numbering our rows from 1 to 10):

f(s, 1) = 1

for all values of "s".

Also, and this is where the insight comes in, (Using *Mathematica*-ish notation)

```
f(s, r) = Sum[ f(i, r-1) * fits(s, i) , {i, 1, 3328} ]
```

where "fits" is a function that takes two scenario numbers and returns "1" if you can legally stack those two rows on top of each other and "0" if you can't.  This uses the insight because the number of legal ways to place scenario depends only on the number of ways to place scenarios above it that are compatible according to "fits".

Now, fits can be precomputed and stored in a 3328 by 3328 array of bytes.  That's only about 10 Meg of memory.  (Less if you get fancy and store it as a bit array)

The answer then is obviously just

```
Sum[ f(i, 10) , {i, 1, 3328} ]
```

Comment: I don't understand how you compute f(s,r) can you illuminate me on this.

Comment: @Morpheus - Your question is too vague for me to adequately answer it; what specifically don't you understand? `f(s,r)` is computed by the given formulas; `f(s, 1) = 1`, and `f(s,2) = f(1,1)*fits(s,1) + f(2,1)*fits(s,2) + f(3,1)*fits(s,3) + ... + f(3328,1)*fits(s,3328)`, and you get `f(s,r)` for larger `r` similarly.

But that's what I've already said above, so you must be asking something else.

Comment: thanks for the response. I was about to say fits(s,i) actually, would u give some sort of pseudo code so i could picturize it little clearly, how do we go about stacking two rows on top of each other!

Answer (score 4):

Here is my answer.  It's Haskell, among other things, you get bignums for free.

EDIT: It now actually solves the problem in a reasonable amount of time.

MORE EDITS: With a sparse matrix it takes a half a second on my computer.

You compute each possible way to tile a row.  Let's say there are N ways to tile a row.  Make an NxN matrix.  Element i,j is 1 if row i can appear next to row j, 0 otherwise.  Start with a vector containing N 1s.  Multiply the matrix by the vector a number of times equal to the height of the wall minus 1, then sum the resulting vector.

```
module Main where
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Data.List
import System.Environment
import Text.Printf
import qualified Data.Foldable as F
import Data.Word
import Data.Bits

-- This records the index of the holes in a bit field
type Row = Word64

-- This generates the possible rows for given block sizes and row length
genRows :: [Int] -> Int -> [Row]
genRows xs n = map (permToRow 0 1) $ concatMap comboPerms $ combos xs n
  where
    combos [] 0 = return []
    combos [] _ = [] -- failure
    combos (x:xs) n =
      do c <- [0..(n `div` x)]
         rest <- combos xs (n - x*c)
         return (if c > 0 then (x, c):rest else rest)
    comboPerms [] = return []
    comboPerms bs =
      do (b, brest) <- choose bs
         rest <- comboPerms brest
         return (b:rest)
    choose bs = map (\(x, _) -> (x, remove x bs)) bs
    remove x (bc@(y, c):bs) =
      if x == y
         then if c > 1
                 then (x, c - 1):bs
                 else bs
         else bc:(remove x bs)
    remove _ [] = error "no item to remove"
    permToRow a _ [] = a
    permToRow a _ [_] = a
    permToRow a n (c:cs) =
      permToRow (a .|. m) m cs where m = n `shiftL` c

-- Test if two rows of blocks are compatible
-- i.e. they do not have a hole in common
rowCompat :: Row -> Row -> Bool
rowCompat x y = x .&. y == 0

-- It's a sparse matrix with boolean entries
type Matrix = Array Int [Int]
type Vector = UArray Int Word64

-- Creates a matrix of row compatibilities
compatMatrix :: [Row] -> Matrix
compatMatrix rows = listArray (1, n) $ map elts [1..n] where
  elts :: Int -> [Int]
  elts i = [j | j <- [1..n], rowCompat (arows ! i) (arows ! j)]
  arows = listArray (1, n) rows :: UArray Int Row
  n = length rows

-- Multiply matrix by vector, O(N^2)
mulMatVec :: Matrix -> Vector -> Vector
mulMatVec m v = array (bounds v)
    [(i, sum [v ! j | j <- m ! i]) | i <- [1..n]]
  where n = snd $ bounds v

initVec :: Int -> Vector
initVec n = array (1, n) $ zip [1..n] (repeat 1)

main = do
  args <- getArgs
  if length args < 3
    then putStrLn "usage: blocks WIDTH HEIGHT [BLOCKSIZE...]"
    else do
      let (width:height:sizes) = map read args :: [Int]
      printf "Width: %i\nHeight %i\nBlock lengths: %s\n" width height
             $ intercalate ", " $ map show sizes
      let rows = genRows sizes width
      let rowc = length rows
      printf "Row tilings: %i\n" rowc
      if null rows
        then return ()
        else do
          let m = compatMatrix rows
          printf "Matrix density: %i/%i\n"
                 (sum (map length (elems m))) (rowc^2)
          printf "Wall tilings: %i\n" $ sum $ elems
                  $ iterate (mulMatVec m) (initVec (length rows))
                            !! (height - 1)
```

And the results...

```
$ time ./a.out 64 10 4 6
Width: 64
Height 10
Block lengths: 4, 6
Row tilings: 3329
Matrix density: 37120/11082241
Wall tilings: 806844323190414

real    0m0.451s
user    0m0.423s
sys     0m0.012s
```

Okay, 500 ms, I can live with that.

Comment: I don't understand how you arrived @ the N*1 Matrix

Comment: Dietrich, " Start with a vector containing N 1s. Multiply the matrix by the vector a number of times equal to the height of the wall minus 1, then sum the resulting vector."  Just to clarify, this means multiple the resultant Nx1 vector from the matrix multiplication by the sparse matrix Height-1 times?

Comment: @Jreeter: Yes, I believe so.  The wording is a little clumsy since I usually think about matrix x vector multiplication with the vector on the right.  So if the matrix is M and the vector is V, the result is `M^(height-1)V`.

Comment: Dietrich, thanks.. One more thing how did you come to think of using this method? I am trying to really understand how this works in relation to this problem.

Comment: Each element in the vector, row in the matrix, and column in the matrix corresponds to a pattern X.  An element in the vector records the number of different ways to build a height N wall which has pattern X on the top.  So `(4, 3, 9)` means 4 possible walls with pattern #1, 3 with #2, and 9 with #3.  Multiplying the matrix by the vector for height N gives you the vector for height N+1.  If you go through the definition for matrix multiplication and work out a small example, you can see how it works.

Comment: As a matter of how I thought of of this method, you get an intuition for recognizing things like "Oh, I recognize that -- that's matrix multiplication."  Then you can go through and prove that matrix multiplication solves the problem, or if you are very good at math (post-graduate), your intuition is developed enough that you skip the proof because you think it's obvious.  (This is why some math professors find it difficult to teach math.)

Comment: I am able to generate the same row tilings and matrix density in the sparse matrix. The sparse matrix is 3329x3329, as you say above(NxN), but with my current java implementation calculating  (3329x3329)^9 is out of the question, it results in a very large amount of operations.  I must be missing something important in your method.

Comment: @Jreeter: Let A be the matrix we're talking about.  A is quite sparse.  However, A^K gets increasingly dense as K increases.  I suspect there are no zeroes at all once K hits 3 or so.  So computing A^K is out of the question, but we don't need to compute A^K.  We only need to compute A^K*V, where V is our starting vector.  Multiplication is associative, so we can compute it as `A(A(...A(AV))...))` instead of `((...(AA)A...)A)V`.  This gives us a number of operations on the order of O(N*M), where N is the height and M is the number of *nonzero* entries in the matrix.

Comment: By comparison, computing A^N directly will cost about O(J^3*log(N)), where J is the width of the matrix and N is the height of the wall.  As you can see, computing A^N directly becomes more efficient if N is very large.  Of course, this is using naive matrix multiplication, but using a better multiplication algorithm will only move J^3 closer to J^2.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dietrich, I was able to reach the solution. Although mine is much slower, ~4.5 seconds. :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem for a programming contest tiling a long hallway with tiles of various shapes.  I used dynamic programming: given any panel, there is a way to construct it by laying down one row at a time.  Each row can have finitely many shapes at its end.  So for each number of rows, for each shape, I compute how many ways there are to make that row.  (For the bottom row, there is exactly one way to make each shape.)  Then the shape of each row determines the number of shapes that the next row can take (i.e. never line up the spaces).  This number is finite for each row and in fact because you have only two sizes of bricks, it is going to be small.  So you wind up spending constant time per row and the program finishes quickly.

To represent a shape I would just make a list of 4's and 6's, then use this list as a key in a table to store the number of ways to make that shape in row *i*, for each *i*.

Comment: Hi, Can you elaborate on the method a little for me to understand?? it would be really helpful!

Comment: Request code, difficult to understand otherwise.