# Bin-packing solution: what's going on with this?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, np-complete

I've attempted to implement a solution to [a bin-packing-type problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913566/has-anyone-solved-a-programming-puzzle-similar-to-this), mostly in the way [described by Dietrich Epp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/925367/1907186). I don't do Haskell yet so I wrote something in C++.

For a wall width lower than a certain number (36), my program and the Haskell program give identical results. For any wall 36 units wide or wider, my result is much lower. I'm doubtful that my solution is the correct one since the other poster has a lot of "rep" here. I believe the problem is that my bit matrix is populated with a much lower number of 1's than should be.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

const int NARROW_W = 6;     // 3
const int WIDE_W = 9;       // 4.5

const int MIN_WALL_W = 6;   // 3
const int MAX_WALL_W = 96;  // 48
const int MIN_WALL_H = 1;
const int MAX_WALL_H = 10;

// precomputed factorials for finding # of combos
static const long long fact[] =
{
    1,
    1,
    2,
    6,
    24,
    120,
    720,
    5040,
    40320,
    362880,
    3628800,
39916800,
479001600,
6227020800
};

using namespace std;

typedef vector<unsigned long long> LongVec;
typedef vector< vector<int> > IntMat;

LongVec operator * (const IntMat &a, const LongVec &b); // O(n^2)

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int width, height;
    int lcm; // Lowest Common Multiple
    int narrowc, widec;
    bool valid;
    unsigned rowc;
    IntMat bit_mat, gap_vecs, block_vecs;
    vector<int> gaps, blocks;
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    unsigned long long result;
    LongVec vec_res;

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " [width] [height]\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    width = (int) (strtod(argv[1], NULL) * 2);
    height = (int) strtod(argv[2], NULL);
    if (width < MIN_WALL_W || width > MAX_WALL_W)
    {
        cerr << "Width out of range\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (height < MIN_WALL_H || height > MAX_WALL_H)
    {
        cerr << "Height out of range\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // see if valid row is possible
    // by removing narrows and adding wides until width is reached
    narrowc = width / NARROW_W;
    widec = 0;
    valid = false;
    if (width % NARROW_W > 0)
    {
        while (narrowc > 0 && !valid)
        {
            narrowc--;
            widec = 0;
            do
                widec++;
            while ((widec * WIDE_W) + (narrowc * NARROW_W) < width);
            if ((widec * WIDE_W) + (narrowc * NARROW_W) == width)
                valid = true;
        }
    }
    else valid = true;
    if (!valid)
    {
        cout << 0;
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    // find valid rows
    lcm = WIDE_W;
    while (lcm % WIDE_W != 0 || lcm % NARROW_W != 0)
        lcm++;
    rowc = 0;
    while (narrowc >= 0)
    {
        rowc += (unsigned) (fact[narrowc + widec] /
            (fact[narrowc] * fact[widec]));

        block_vecs.reserve(rowc);
        gap_vecs.reserve(rowc);

        blocks.clear();
        for (j = 0; j < narrowc; j++)
        {
            blocks.push_back(NARROW_W);
        }
        for (j = 0; j < widec; j++)
        {
            blocks.push_back(WIDE_W);
        }
        block_vecs.push_back(blocks);

        gap_vecs.push_back(blocks);
        for (j = 1; j < gap_vecs.back().size() - 1; j++)
        {
            gap_vecs.back().at(j) += gap_vecs.back().at(j - 1);
        }
        gap_vecs.back().pop_back();

        if (widec > 0 && narrowc > 0)
        {
            while (next_permutation(blocks.begin(), blocks.end()))
            {
                block_vecs.push_back(blocks);

                gap_vecs.push_back(blocks);
                for (j = 1; j < gap_vecs.back().size() - 1; j++)
                {
                    gap_vecs.back().at(j) += gap_vecs.back().at(j - 1);
                }
                gap_vecs.back().pop_back();
            }
        }

        narrowc -= lcm / NARROW_W;
        widec += lcm / WIDE_W;
    }

    // fill bit matrix
    bit_mat.reserve(rowc);
    vector<int> v(gap_vecs.at(0).size() * 2);
    for (i = 0; i < rowc; i++)
    {
        gaps.clear();
        bit_mat.push_back(gaps);
        gaps = gap_vecs.at(i);
        for (j = 0; j < rowc; j++)
        {
            //v.clear();
            it = set_intersection(gaps.begin(), gaps.end(),
                    gap_vecs.at(j).begin(), gap_vecs.at(j).end(), v.begin());
            if ((int) (it - v.begin()) != 0)
            {
                bit_mat.back().push_back(0);
            }
            else
            {
                bit_mat.back().push_back(1);
            }
        }
    }

    // multiply vector of 1's by bit matrix (height - 1) times
    vec_res.assign(rowc, 1);
    for (i = 0; i < height - 1; i++)
    {
        vec_res = bit_mat * vec_res;
    }
    result = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < vec_res.size(); i++)
        result += vec_res.at(i);

    cout << result;

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

LongVec operator * (const IntMat &a, const LongVec &b)
{
    int i, j;
    int m = a.size();
    int n = b.size();

    LongVec result(m);

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        result[i] = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            result[i] += a[i][j] * b[j];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I suspect that, if this isn't giving the right solution, the set_intersection() function isn't doing what it's supposed to do (see if there are any matches between two sets of "gap" indexes). Any ideas? I'm compiling with g++ on Mac OS X 10.8.

Comment: Just a guess, but probably you're using 32-bit numbers and some number overflows when you hit width 37. Oh, and bin-packing is different.

Comment: @rici Thanks; I'll fiddle with data types a bit. For a 48x10 wall, though, the number of matrix elements (3329x3329) fits into 32 bits.

Comment: @rici no overflow occurs, since a compile with -ftrapv had the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
// precomputed factorials for finding # of combos
static const long long fact[] =
{
    1,
    1,
    2,
    6,
    24,
    120,
    720,
    5040,
    40320,
    362880,
    3628800,
    39916800,
    479001600,
    6227020800
};
```

You are missing a few factorials, in

```
   rowc += (unsigned) (fact[narrowc + widec] /
        (fact[narrowc] * fact[widec]));
```

you may need 16! for your limits. Add

```
              ,
    87178291200,
    1307674368000,
    20922789888000
```

in the appropriate place.

Comment: Good point, though I actually removed the whole factorial business because "row count" is computed by incrementing it each time a permutation of "gaps" is added to the vector of vectors.

Comment: Well, adding that made it spit out the right values for me, doesn't it for you?